# What is the biblical basis for All Saint's Day?

Tags: biblical-basis, halloween

As an Evangelical Christian, I recently had a debate about why I do not celebrate Halloween. Their response was that the origins of Halloween come from the Christian "All Saint's Day" (which is actually the day after Halloween).

I would like to know if there is any mention of All Saint's Day in the bible, and if not, is there any biblical basis for the tradition of All Saint's Day in the bible?

Comment: I do not believe one can add to @DavidStratton's succinct answer below. One comment is that for this *Solemnity*, the First reading of the Mass is from Rev [7:2-4, 9-14](http://www.usccb.org/bible/readings/110114.cfm). It is worthwhile to read it.

Comment: The secularized Halloween (dressing up like ghosts and devils and all that stuff) is an obscene perversion of All Saints Day. As a Catholic, I celebrate All Saint's Day but not the secularized version of it.

Comment: You say All Saints Day is the day after Halloween. That is factually true, but a bit like saying that Christmas is the day after Christmas Eve. Halloween is a shortening of All Hallows' Eve (All Hallows Day being the same as All Saints Day, Halloween is the evening before All Saints Day.).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a verse search question.

Comment: @curiousdannii The wording of the question implied (at least to me) more than mere "is this mentioned in the bible."  I've made it more clearly a biblical basis question.

Comment: Strange thing that Halloween is celebrated in modern cultures, where as historically this day was the Vigil of All Saints and as such was a traditional fast day!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, there are not references to All Saints Day in the Bible.

The tradition of All Saints Day originated long after the books of the Bible were written.

From [Catholic Online](http://www.catholic.org/saints/allsaints/)

> The origin of the festival of All Saints celebrated in the West dates
>   to May 13, 609 or 610, when Pope Boniface IV consecrated the Pantheon
>   at Rome to the Blessed Virgin and all the martyrs; the feast of the
>   dedicatio Sanctae Mariae ad Martyres has been celebrated at Rome ever
>   since. There is evidence that from the fifth through the seventh
>   centuries there existed in certain places and at sporadic intervals a
>   feast date 13 May to celebrate the holy martyrs.[4] The origin of All
>   Saints' Day cannot be traced with certainty, and it has been observed
>   on various days in different places. However, there are some who
>   maintain the belief that it has origins in the pagan observation of 13
>   May, the Feast of the Lemures, in which the malevolent and restless
>   spirits of the dead were propitiated. Liturgiologists base the idea
>   that this Lemuria festival was the origin of that of All Saints on
>   their identical dates and on the similar theme of "all the dead".[5]
>
> The feast of All Saints, on its current date, is traced to the
>   foundation by Pope Gregory III (731.741) of an oratory in St. Peter's
>   for the relics "of the holy apostles and of all saints, martyrs and
>   confessors, of all the just made perfect who are at rest throughout
>   the world", with the day moved to 1 November and the 13 May feast
>   suppressed.[6]

Comment: In the Daily Roman Missal According to the *Roman Missal, Thirds Edition,* for this Solemnity it says, **"This feast celebrates all the unknown saints who are now in Heaven. Sanctity is within everyone's reach; through the Communion of Saints each part of the Mystical Body of Christ helps every other to grow in holiness."**